# How can I invoke a RefreshCache function with Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I deployed an SMB file gateway on AWS for a customer, but it is not synchronizing with the S3 bucket. I would like to trigger a Lambda function using CloudWatch Events everytime there is a change in the bucket (PUT or DELETE) and invoke a RefreshCache function with that Lambda function. Examples are very complicated and I feel so helpless. Please help! Any examples with explanation is fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using CloudWatch Events for this is the correct approach. You should simply configure the S3 bucket to directly trigger a Lambda function on any new object events, or object delete events.

When you have this configured, the S3 bucket will send events to the Lambda function in the format documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html).

Inside the Lambda function you would iterate over the `Records` in that event message, using the object `key` value in each record as the path that needs to be refreshed in the cache.

Comment: Much appreciated, Mark.